# "In flutter route is the path to the screen" or "In flutter one screen is known as one route"

Tags: flutter, routes

In Lesson 1's 18th video of Udacity's Build Native Mobile App with Flutter course, the instructor says "In flutter one screen is known as one route"
 in 
But there is clarification also that 
"In flutter route is the path to the screen".

So which statement is right and why ?

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, Route is referring to full fledge screen.
But you can't say all pages extended by stateless or Statefull widgets are routes.

For new beginners understandings, if your page have scaffold widget then it will consider as new route.

Answer (score 0):

Simply a **Route** is a page it is just a matter of names such as screen, page and route they mean the same thing. Everything is a widget in flutter so pages are also widgets like buttons or textFields.